# the stubbed value is not being return when I mock on a class

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking, mockito

I am mocking  a class and stubbing one of the method to return the value i want but since i need to pass .class value the mocked data is not being returned. any insights is appreciated.

```
public class Generator{

   public int getSomething(){
      return 1;
   }
 }

public class Utility{

 public void generate(java.lang.Class<?> class){

  }

 }

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TestClass extends Utility{

 @Test
 public void test()

 Generator gen = Mockito.spy(Generator.class)
 Mockito.when(gen.getSomething()).thenReturn(4);

  Int x = generate(gen.getClass())
 // in here 1 is being returned instead of 4
}
```

}

Comment: Any reason why you're using a spy, not a mock?

Comment: Which class has the `generate` method and what does it do?  Be aware that `getClass()` won't give you the same result on a mock or a spy as it would on an ordinary object.

Comment: generate is a method in a Utility class that i am using to call generator

Comment: That's probably where the problem is.

Comment: I think the issue might be i am using getClass() method. How is the result i get from that method different on object i get from spy?

Comment: Mockito makes a brand new class for the spy object. So getClass on the spy returns a different value from getClass on an unspied object of the same declared class.

Answer (score 0):

for spy Object that is diferent from mock object

try

```
Mockito.doReturn(4).when(gen).getSomething();
```

below code works for me perfectly fine

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TestClass {
    @Test
     public void test() {

     Generator gen = Mockito.spy(Generator.class);

     Mockito.doReturn(4).when(gen).getSomething();
     assertEquals(4, gen.getSomething());
    }
}

class Generator{

       public int getSomething(){
          return 1;
       }
     }
```

Comment: Worth noting that this method works for both spies and mocks.  The `Mockito.when` method is a bit fussier.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem if u think this is the possible solution u mind upvoting the answer :)

Comment: This didnt work for me, i am getting the same result. I am using spying so that i am only partial mocking that class